# Is $f(z)=\frac{z^{2}-1}{z-1}$ continous at $z=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

My teacher said no, but doesn't $f(z)=z+1$ which is continuous?

Comment: In a broader sense, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not continuous at $z=1$ because it is not defined there. If you plug $z=1$ in $\frac{z^2-1}{z-1}$, you obtain $\frac{0}{0}$ which is not defined.

You can't divide the numerator by $z-1$ if $z=1$, because then you're dividing by zero!

Answer (score 4):

Basically: The function is **not defined** at $z=1$ so in particular it cannot be continuous.

But yes: it can be *continuously extended* by setting $f(1)=2$, see for example [What is a continuous extension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553231/what-is-a-continuous-extension)

Answer (score 1):

A function $f$ which is continuous at point $t$:
 1. should be defined at the point $t$: $f(t)$ exists;
 2. should have limit when $x$ tends to $t$: $\lim_{x\to t}f(x)$ exists;
 3.  $f(t) = \lim_{x\to t}f(x)$ .

In this problem, $f(z)= z+1$ except $z=1$ and not defined at $z=1$.
If we can define $f(z)$ at $1$ , $f(1)=2$ then we can say $f(z)$ is continuous at $z=1$.

Sometimes you can misunderstand that "there exists a limit value" as "a function be continuous at that point".

Comment: thanks for the editing, It's my first visit here and English is not my mother language. If you have more time then can you tell me how I can edit like yours, (math format)?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick tutorial :)