# Is $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ continuous at $x=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

A function $f$ is said to be continuous if $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=f(a)$

Now when we evaluate a function like $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ as $x \to 1$ we find that the limit is 2.

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1} =\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)}=\lim\limits_{x \to 1}(x+1)=2$$

but the function $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ itself is not defined at $x=1$.

Does this mean this function is not continuous at $x=1$?

Comment: Yes, it does. For a function to be continuous at a point it must exist at said point.

Comment: However, it can be extended by continuity at $x=0$.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1476310, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/462199, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1998842 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2-1%7D%7Bx-1%7D%20%24%2C%20AND%20content%3Acontinuous)

Comment: @Kyky when you say "yes, it does", note the question in the title is the opposite of the final question in the text.  Presumably you intended "yes, this means the function is *not* continuous at $x=1$"

Comment: I intended to reply to the question at the end of the question, good catch.

Comment: @Invisible You mean at $x=1$

Comment: @MartinR The duplicate in the close vote has a slight difference to the case here, namely that the limit does not exist (or is it a typo and it should be $x-2$ in the denominator ?) As written, the function in the duplicate cannot even be made continous by adding a point.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, I had noticed that (too late) and [suggested in CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59731620#59731620) to chose one of the questions from my other comment as a duplicate target. Both https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1476310 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1998842 are the *identical* question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this mean this function is not continuous at $x=1$?

Yes, and you give the correct reason, that is, $f(1)$ does not exist.

However, $f$ can be extended in order to make it continuous:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}  \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}   &\text{ if } x\neq 1 \\
          2  &\text{ if } x=1\end{cases}$$

is a continuous function and is equivalent to the function $f(x) = x+1\ (\forall x\in\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: So you mean the way..... I defined $f(x)$ was not correct....but

Comment: Well, it would have been better if you stated the domain of your original function. As you wrote it, I assume that the input is all of the real numbers that the function can take, $\ \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\},\ $ in which case of course the function is well-defined. But it is not continuous at $\ x=1.\ $ In fact, you shouldn't even been talking about $\ x=1\ $ because $\ x=1\ $ is not a part of the domain. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20domain%20or%20set%20of%20departure,X%20%E2%86%92%20Y%2C%20and%20is%20alternatively%20denoted%20as

Comment: Can I call this a removable discontinuity?

Answer (score 1):

No, your function is not continuous at 1. It doesn't satisfy your definition for continuity at some a. Although the limit exists, $f(1)$ doesn't.