# Is there a closed form for this infinite sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I am wondering is there a closed form for this infinite sum.
$$R(\beta)=\beta^2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(\pi kn/\beta)}{(k^2-\beta^2)^2},$$
where $n\in\mathbb{N},\beta\in\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: For $\beta =1$ it's trivially $0$. Have you tried with the simpler case $\beta =2$ and $n=1$? I don't even think there is a closed form for that.

Comment: there is a closed form of this sum which containes the Lerch function

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Could you, please, say me where can I find it?

Comment: Though, I think the definition of Lerch function is enough for my purpose. Thanks.

Comment: How about putting a link to the Lerch function as an answer to the question?

Comment: So far I cannot answer my question using only definition of Lerch function.

Comment: @Crostul, it is not *trivially* 0 when $\beta = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may start with the expression obtained [using Fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-frac-left/110495#110495) for $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$ and $z$ not a positive integer :
$$\tag{1}\cos(x\,z)=\frac{2\,z\sin(\pi z)}{\pi}\;\left(\frac 1{2z^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \;(-1)^k\frac{\cos(k\,x)}{k^2-z^2}\right)$$
that I'll rewrite as :
$$\cos((\pi-a)z)=\frac{2\,z\sin(\pi z)}{\pi}\;\left(\frac 1{2z^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \;(-1)^k\frac{\cos(k\,(\pi-a))}{k^2-z^2}\right)$$
or simply :
$$\tag{2}\frac{\pi}2\frac{\cos((\pi-a)z)}{z\;\sin(\pi z)}=\frac 1{2z^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \;\frac{\cos(k\,a)}{k^2-z^2}$$
Since $\;\displaystyle\sin^2(x)=\frac {1-\cos(2x)}2\;$ and $\;\displaystyle \frac d{dz}\frac 1{k^2-z^2}=\frac {2z}{(k^2-z^2)^2}\;$ we deduce that for :
\begin{align}
R(a,b)&:=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(k\,a)}{(k^2-b^2)^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{(k^2-b^2)^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {\cos(k\,2a)}{(k^2-b^2)^2}\\
&=\frac 1{2b}\frac d{db}\left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{k^2-b^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {\cos(k\,2a)}{k^2-b^2}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}2\frac 1{2b}\frac d{db}\left[-\frac{\cos(\pi b)}{b\;\sin(\pi b)}+\frac{\cos((\pi-2a)b)}{b\;\sin(\pi b)}\right]\\
\end{align}
and thus the wished closed form for $b$ not a positive integer and $\,a\in(0,\pi)\,$ at least :
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(k\,a)}{(k^2-b^2)^2}=\frac {\pi}{8\,b^3}\left[\cot(\pi b)+\pi b\csc^2(\pi b)-(1+\pi b\cot(\pi b))\csc(\pi b)\cos((\pi-2a)b)-\\(\pi-2a)b\,\csc(\pi b)\sin((\pi-2a)b)\right]$$

pari/gp scripts used for numerical confirmation :

```
r(a,b)=2*sumalt(k=0,sin(k*a)^2/(k^2-b^2)^2)
f(a,b)=Pi/(4*b^3)*(1/tan(Pi*b)+Pi*b/sin(Pi*b)^2-(1+Pi*b/tan(Pi*b))/sin(Pi*b)*cos((Pi-2*a)*b)-(Pi-2*a)*b/sin(Pi*b)*sin((Pi-2*a)*b))
```

Comment: For $\,a\not \in(0,\pi)\,$ simply replace $a$ by $(a \bmod{\pi})$ in the RHS.

Comment: In my question $a=\frac{1}{b}$ I suspect that in this case the step when you take a derivative would be other, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Wolfgang: yes setting $\,a=\dfrac{\pi kn}b\,$ at the start would be counterproductive and that's why I searched a more general expression. Your substitution should be done at the end in the expression I obtained or in : $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(k\,a)}{(k^2-b^2)^2}=\frac {\pi}8\frac{\frac{\cos(\pi b)}b+\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi b)}-\left(\frac 1b+\frac{\pi}{\tan(\pi b)}\right)\cos((\pi-2a)b)-(\pi-2a)\sin((\pi-2a)b)}{b^2\,\sin(\pi b)}$$

Comment: It seems I got it. Thanks. I will check every step again and hope will accept your answer.

Comment: A little bit strange. Let $\beta = n$ and $a = \pi$. Then sum is equal (the only non-zero summon ) to $\pi^2/4$. On the other hand, according to your answer it is $-\pi^2/8$. I  think you should require $a\in(0,2\pi)$ this eliminates the minus. But I do not know how to get rid of extra 2 in the denominator.

Comment: Sorry. Requiring $a\in(0,2\pi)$ does not eliminate the minus. But this should be required if $x\in(-\pi, \pi)$ and $x = \pi - a$.

Comment: @Wolfgang: Well I explicitly excluded the case $b$ a positive integer since $R$ is not defined in this case. Anyway computing the limit I obtained $\;\displaystyle\lim_{b\to n} g_n(b)=\dfrac {\pi^2}4$ for $g_n(b):=b^2 R(\pi n/b,b)$ (using the closed form). Of course the limit has to be evaluated with care (you can't simply substitute $b=n\,$ and $\,a=\pi$ !). Concerning the initial interval $a\in(0,2\pi)$ becoming $a\in(0,\pi)$ this comes from $\cos(k\,a)$ in $(2)$ becoming $\cos(k\,2a)$ in the derivation (I should have changed the name of the variable or replaced $a$ by $a/2$ at the right).

Comment: This sum defined wherever it is converged. So it is defined at $\beta = n$ and more over, at $\beta=m$ any integer. How did you obtain $\pi^2/4$ using the closed form? It is $-\pi^2/8$.

Comment: OK. It is either $-\pi^2/8$ or $\pi^2/8$ depending on how does $b$ approaches to $n$. I do not understand so. It is because of the last sine.

Comment: I am idiot. Sorry. Sign is always plus. But what about extra 2?

Comment: @Wolfgang: Your series is not defined for $\beta$ a positive integer (for the same reason that [$\dfrac {\sin(x)}x$ is not defined at $0$ but may trivially be extended](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/553376/21783)).  
There is no extra 2 factor, the last sin(e ;-)) adds indeed a contribution $\pi$ to the other $\pi$ giving at the end $\dfrac {\pi(\pi+\pi)}8$ as wished (in my previous comment the $R$ function was without the $2$ overall factor, sorry for the confusion).

Comment: Firstly, I do not understand how sine could add a contribution larger than 1.

Comment: Secondly, I do not understand where do you take $\pi+\pi$ from. I tried to figure out. Honestly.

Comment: @Wolfgang: From the closed form I presented in the comment :
$\lim_{b\to n}\frac 1{\sin((\pi b)}\left(\frac{\cos(\pi b)}b+\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi b)}-\left(\frac 1b+\frac{\pi}{\tan(\pi b)}\right)\cos((\pi-2\pi n/b)b)\right)=\pi$ and (the "$\sin$ term") $\lim_{b\to n}\frac 1{\sin((\pi b)}\left(-(\pi-2\pi n/b)\sin((\pi-2\pi n/b)b)\right)=\pi$ (note btw that the substitution $b=n$ would give $-\pi$ instead of $\pi$ for the second limit). Hoping this clarified all the remaining points,

Comment: OMG. So sorry. I thought that all except the last sine term is zero. It needs to be more accurate. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped @Wolfgang. Excellent continuation,